# What is the bundle seed id for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

In order to share keychain information between applications, we needed to setup a shared keychain access group.
Before the sharing would work correctly, both apps needed to have provisioning based on the same bundle seed ID.
I wants to know what is that seed id is it same as app id or different ?

Two share keychain information my both apps should be on the appstore. Because I just make an sample project to check sharing of keychain information. Is it possible to do that without publishing it to Appstore?

Note :- My bundle id is just "com.comapny_name.myapp" and in Itunes connect I am able to see only my app id - (10 digit number) and bundle id which is same as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

According to AppYourself.net on [this page,](https://support.appyourself.net/entries/20812846-Apple-app-ID)

> Each App ID consists of a universally unique 10 character "Bundle Seed ID" prefix generated by Apple and a "Bundle Identifier" suffix that is entered by a Team Admin in the Provisioning Portal. The recommended practice is to use a reverse-domain name style string for the “Bundle Identifier” portion of the App ID. An example App ID would be: 8E549T7128.com.apple.AddressBook.

As such, the bundle seed ID is part of the app ID.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My bundle id is just "com.comapny_name.myapp" and in Itunes connect I am able to see only my app id and bundle id which is same as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to add a new app. 
There is link there to create a new bundle Id. 
https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleCreate.action
On this page

```
  App ID Prefix
```

value is your bundle seed Id.